# Asymptotics or methods for this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics

I was wondering if there is some "good" numerical method, or some cool asymptotic method, for this integral:

> $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{\Gamma(x+1)} \ln\left(\frac{1+\Gamma(x+1)}{1+x}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

$\texttt{W. Mathematica}$ returns the value

$$0.0057963275757687840000000$$

(I do not know if there are problems in the application or if it is a really exact result, in this case a rational expression would be trivial to get).

Pushed by the curiosity, I plotted it and it follows that the greatest part of the integration is covered between $0$ and $17$, even if, as an estimation, we could stop at $7-8$:

[image]

So basically: how can we attack this integral?

Comment: Here by $x!$, I assume you're tacitly using the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: Immediately what comes to mind is to pull out an "$x!$" from the log and use two approximations, Stirlings on $\log\Gamma(x+1)$, and Taylor series on $\log(1+(\Gamma(x+1))^{-1})$

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes, indeed. I'm so "used" to write $x!$ that I forgot. Edited!

Comment: What do you mean by asymptotic expression? As of now, your integral is just a real number, with no dependence. I think you probably mean approximation instead of asymptotics. Something more interesting than just trying to approximate it is to insert a parameter and then perhaps look at, this time indeed, the asymptotics as the parameter reaches a certain value. Right now, I don't see any method that could be useful for this integral. There might be a way to do it using complex analysis.

Comment: @Zachary Whoops my bad, I meant a series expansion to analyse the behaviour for large $x$ and small $x$ (even for large $x$ Stirling shall work). In any case this made me to think about asymptotic in two cases: when there is an additional parameter $t$ inside the first/second $\sin$ term and inside the $\ln$ term, and when $t$ is part of the $\Gamma$ argument too. I guess it's late to edit this question, I wonder if I shall ask another separate one or not.

Comment: @Zachary In the meantime, I will work by myself on them!

Comment: *Mathematica* can give a more precise answer using the `WorkingPrecision` option:  `NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]` results in 0.0057963275757927044721188809400551403716646550550859.  How precise do you need the answer?  Or are you expecting some "nice looking" answer with $\pi$ or Euler's constant?

Comment: @JimB Well I already used W. Mathematica. My question concerned the possibility to obtain a "good" result in other ways, and maybe why not a closed form like some nice looking expression in terms of mathematical constants like $e$, $\pi$, $\log$ or Riemann Zeta :D

Comment: Not all definite integrals have "nice looking expressions".  What makes you think that one exists for this integral?  Also, your integral is being discussed at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278635/asymptoticintegrate-of-a-difficult-integral?noredirect=1#comment695852_278635.

Comment: @JimB If I have learnt something about MSE is that a "not so random guy" can always impress the crowd by finding some spirited solution (see for example @ Ron Gordon's answers). So who knows? :) 
W. Mathematica has shown many times its limits, contrarily to human fantasy and capacity.